# How do I get the groupby operation to work?

Tags: python, pandas

Can't get Pandas Groupby operation to work.

I suspect I need to convert the data to a pandas dataframe first? However, I can't seem to get that to work either.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
baseurl = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/datasets/githubposting.json"
response = requests.get(baseurl)
data = response.json()
print(data)
def get_number_of_jobs(technology):
 number_of_jobs = 0
 number_of_jobs=data.groupby('technology').sum().loc[technology,:][0]
 return technology,number_of_jobs
print(get_number_of_jobs('python'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list of dictionaries, not `DataFrame`, so it doesn't have `groupby`. You don't really need it anyway, you can create the `DataFrame` while replacing the `A` and `B` columns with the first values in the json response and search for `'Python'` there, it's already a single entry

```
baseurl = "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/module%201/datasets/githubposting.json"
response = requests.get(baseurl)
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(data[0].values()), data=[d.values() for d in data[1:]])
number_of_jobs = df.loc[df['technology'] == 'Python', 'number of job posting'].iloc[0]
print(number_of_jobs) # 51
```

Comment: Thanks so much Guy. This is exactly what I needed. Really appreciate it!